# Finding radius when performing shell method

Tags: calculus

> Find the volume of the region generated by revolving $y = -x^3$ and $y = -\sqrt x$ around the $x$-axis.

I don't understand how the radius component is $-y$; why not $+y$?

Answer (score 0):

The region defined by those equations is in the fourth quadrant, where $y$ is negative. The radius must be positive, so it is written as $|y|$ or $-y$. When $y$ is negative, $-y$ is positive, despite the presence of the minus sign.